# TypeScript type for a perfectly shuffled array

Tags: typescript

This question is purely for fun, not something likely to be needed in the real world, but it didn't feel right to put it on Code Golf, since it's so specific.

Suppose I have the JavaScript:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length === 1) {
        return array;
    }

    const rest = array.slice();
    const middle = rest.splice(Math.ceil(array.length / 2), 1)[0];
    const first = rest.shift();

    return [first, middle, ...shuffle(rest)];
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const shuffled = shuffle(array); // [ 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8 ]
console.log(shuffled);
```

This function essentially shuffles `array` as if it were a deck of cards, perfectly shuffled.  First the top card, then the middle card, then the second card, then the card after the middle card, etc.  Another way to do it would be to split the array in half, zip the two halves together, and flatten the array.

Is it possible to create a TypeScript `type` that will know how to transform `array` into `shuffled`?

This was my best attempt.

```ts
type Shuffle<T extends readonly [...any[]]> = 
    T['length'] extends 0 | 1 ? T : 
    T extends [...infer A, ...infer B]
        ? A['length'] extends B['length'] 
            ? [A, B] extends [[infer AH, ...infer AR], [infer BH, ...infer BR]] 
                ? [AH, BH, ...Shuffle<[...AR, ...BR]>]
                : never
            : never
        : never;

function shuffle<T extends readonly any[]>(array: T): Shuffle<T> {
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length === 1) {
        return array.slice();
    }

    const rest = array.slice();
    const middle = rest.splice(Math.ceil((array.length - 1) / 2), 1)[0];
    const first = rest.shift();

    return [first, middle, ...shuffle(rest)];
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] as const;
const shuffled = shuffle(array);

type Shuffled = typeof shuffled; // never

console.log(shuffle(array));
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgVwGZIDYQDwBUoQB7AQB2AJgM5QBOEAhiQPZGohQDaAdJzUSKwLp8AfFAC8UAFBQpULKwDk6IgHNgcOX1wFi5KAAYoAHygBGKAH4ZUAFwTpl-IVIUOnAJZEkESlACCAGihOdndPbwAhPkk7aQsfeUUVNQ0HbQow+OJE9Vto3ItWfygIzUcdVlYQr18ACQCgyu8fACU+AIqPKrDawLcO8JaNKNzh8zYfbq66znhkNEwXdmap9jCWwUiRkZsiCAA3LyHN7b2Dragd-coAbnFxJAQiAGNgV0YoMkQUdGwS1KpaBhMFjcXhCAAUNEolBoIBsWAAlDYZl9MFhhABvQ6uJBQCFQmHsBKqUQiMT6AxGSHQkCEzLE0liYzwqCYkbUYAIShEKBUglkVCuR4QMHwm52AC+tzsj0YZGA-zloh5+Jp-MFwtFhxlREVAFtXCQSOgldQ5ewyGABUKwQBZGiqdhC1yoMF46m05TEgC0JmZAHooAAmeEBJmsXR8MXSbWKpCuSiKsSm4DmuDY4Aim6Hdmc7msOMJ4ABfWG9DLD6zdBg5PwyPiSXiGPy3ksMSsYwBQMBADMAQALAEAKwBABsAQA7AEABwaGgUJs3JvvT5zEhKisot0wzXiUCQWAr9BrsR7iD0HEb1dXKB+gMXA6N2X0dCE+hKMGXqst+GioA)

Obviously the crux is figuring out how to divide the array in half.

Maybe I could recursively construct two arrays, each time pulling an element off the start and off the end, and placing them in the proper order.... (Once I had this idea, I solved the problem, so I'll post my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) and [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) make it possible, but still a bit hairy, to do the sort of type manipulation you're talking about.

I think the following is the same general approach that you take in your answer, although the exact details are a bit different.  I tried to make the types as "simple" as I could, although I'll leave it up to others to judge how successful that endeavor was:

---

I'll define a type function called `FirstHalf<T>` that returns the first half of a tuple `T`.  If `T` has an odd number of elements then `FirstHalf<T>` will end in the middle element as well.  So `FirstHalf<[1,2,3,4]>` should be `[1,2]`, and `FirstHalf<[1,2,3,4,5]>` should be `[1,2,3]`:

```
type FirstHalf<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer F, ...infer M, any] ?
    [F, ...FirstHalf<M>] : T
```

And then `LastHalf<T>` will return the last half of a tuple type `T` by producing the the complement of `FirstHalf<T>`.  That means if there are an odd number of elements in `T`, the middle element will *not* be in `LastHalf<T>`.  So `LastHalf<[1,2,3,4]>` should be `[3,4]`, and `LastHalf<[1,2,3,4,5]>` should be `[4,5]`:

```
type LastHalf<T extends any[]> = T extends [...FirstHalf<T>, ...infer E] ? E : never;
```

Then, `Interleave<T, U>` will interleave the elements from `T` with elements from `U`, so `Interleave<[1,2,3],["A","B","C"]>` should be `[1,"A",2,"B",3,"C"]`.  If either `T` or `U` has elements left they will just be at the end, so `Interleave<[1,2],["A","B","C","D","E"]>` should be `[1,"A",2,"B","C","D","E"]`:

```
type Interleave<T extends any[], U extends any[]> =
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ? [H, ...Interleave<U, R>] : U
```

(Note that this is achieved by switching the role of `T` and `U` in the recursive call.)

Finally, `Shuffle<T>` will split `T` into its `FirstHalf` and `LastHalf` and `Interleave`s the halves together:

```
type Shuffle<T extends any[]> = Interleave<FirstHalf<[...T]>, LastHalf<[...T]>>;
```

---

I didn't change the implementation of your `shuffle()` function; yes, you need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to convince the compiler that the implementation is safe.  There's almost no chance the compiler would be able to follow that any array manipulation will turn `T` into `Shuffle<T>`.  In the following I use a single call-signature [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to avoid needing assertions inside the body:

```
function shuffle<T extends readonly any[]>(array: T): Shuffle<[...T]>;
function shuffle(array: any[]) {
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length === 1) {
        return array.slice();
    }
    const rest = array.slice();
    const middle = rest.splice(Math.ceil(array.length / 2), 1)[0];
    const first = rest.shift();
    return [first, middle, ...shuffle(rest)];
};
```

---

And let's test it:

```
const shuffled = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] as const);
// const shuffled: [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]
console.log(shuffled); // [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]

const oddShuffled = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] as const);
// const oddShuffled: [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4]
console.log(oddShuffled); // [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4]
```

Yep, looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7ABIEMA2AzAPAFSggA9gIA7AEySnXJAG0BdAPigF4pCSyqaG45bBASwANFAB00wcNEBZCXRBMoAfgCwAKCi6oDGBOmT4yNFjzyWqgFxdt20JCgAZdCgw4CRUhWq16ZjZObl8+fWNTDwsCFiMZIREoAFFVNRSoO3IIADcRAG4HLSdoAElyMgRMCHQ87x4-GmVmCQBVH15-ZtYObT0uDsb9WSTUeMkR0QAlNP0xqWlyyuraiFxWiSnrTKhWopKoAGUACwBXbGxq+rCuwJ7OJZEVuqjzLwZjfFYJN2j3z9YLEKWm02FO5AAxsA4AB7chQJBnC5XUKdGgIGqUOGYEABRisAAU6AQCHQIDs+AAlHYTudLmsPtIvkDQeCobD4Yi6dUiSSyXZupSoABvPp6ODYKC80kgSTVcgAc2Axw47E4AAYoAAfLW0Pmy+VKlVqzgARiFop0-T0GOApwQ8OJMskSEwcAhEAJlOB-QAvmLdBC4SgoBiQ5wnWSXW6PV6fXog+QQwBbOCUSjVDihiAoF1gGOe+ToZWSD1wTDSqOG5VQAD0UAATJSJOaGOqmPHA8HgFBsIhw9nc4iJcA4wHs3aHfo+2YJKn09VxlzkZ6w8BKR3tP6QVpEyHl-TKFmDzyGKaJA2JABmCQAFgkAFYJAA2CQAdgkAA5VO4oHv18Ctb1v+CJIoedhno+F4vte753l+TDaHuMLVHKMIKgSJ4QJQ3p1vWkFQE+jYwVAN5QB+UD3lA35FCBMLprSK5HpwWEEgRl6kfBhEkW+P40P+3raEBf7dlA9GUIx4H6Oe3HEVAr6ceRd6IbuwYoRAaEYeJknVDh+R4dJUFyQpZEUbeqhAA)

Comment: Before realizing I had my own solution, I was about to type "Can't wait to see jcalz's answer for this."

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's the solution I came up with.

```ts
type SplitEven<T extends readonly any[], Start extends any[] = [], End extends any[] = []> =
    T['length'] extends 0 | 1 ? [[...Start, ...T], End] :
    T extends readonly [infer S, ...infer M, infer E] ? SplitEven<M, [...Start, S], [E, ...End]> :
    never;

type Shuffle<T extends readonly any[]> =
    T['length'] extends 0 | 1
        ? T
        : SplitEven<T> extends infer A
            ? A extends readonly [readonly [infer AH, ...infer AR], readonly [infer BH, ...infer BR]]
                ? [AH, BH, ...Shuffle<[...AR, ...BR]>]
                : never
            : never;

function shuffle<T extends readonly any[]>(array: T): Shuffle<T> {
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length === 1) {
        return array.slice() as Shuffle<T>;
    }

    const rest = array.slice();
    const middle = rest.splice(Math.ceil(array.length / 2), 1)[0];
    const first = rest.shift();

    return [first, middle, ...shuffle(rest)] as Shuffle<T>;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] as const;
const shuffled = shuffle(array);

type Shuffled = typeof shuffled; // [1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]

console.log(shuffled);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.1.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=29#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-AAMz8AALPwACs-AAGz8AA7PwAAckGUEhixIeqmpWCocjAaWq4WtasorNAJZaixUA8QwHpsfx8zbjuaGERhJHYeReFUTSiENgwVh+gw1jGqJoFttaXFAA)

Both the function and the type work with odd-length arrays, too.

The only thing left is figure out whether I can avoid the `as Shuffle<T>` in the return statements.  I suspect the second one is beyond TSC's capability since it would need to know how `rest`, `middle`, and `first` were determined, but I'm surprised the first one wasn't inferred.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the type is supposed to check but it's not even checking for something basic like the array length. I removed 'middle' from the returned array and no errors.

Comment: @user2369284 What do you mean?  If you created a new array of type `Shuffled`, the *only* valid value is `[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]`.

Comment: @user2369284 Oh!  You mean the checking in `shuffle()` itself.  No, the `Shuffle` type is to let us know what the return type of `shuffle()` is.  Without the `as Shuffle<T>` in the return statements, `shuffle()` complains that the array doesn't extend `Shuffle<T>`.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you were getting at. It looks a bit weird at first to want a type for concrete values but interesting thought!!